# problems de-serealizing json rest service output with rest sharp

Tags: json, restsharp

My rest service returns the JSON below but for some reason Rest sharp is not de-serealizing the response into objects correctly. Can anybody see whats going on here? The "response" object is getting set but the "stores" array/List inside it is always set to null.

I tried Michael stum's article at http://www.stum.de/2009/12/22/using-restsharp-to-consume-restful-web-services/ and a few variations on the code below, cant seem to get it right. Any ideas?

JSON:

```
{
"stores": [
{
"name": "Group Health"
},
{
"name": "QFC - Seattle/Rainier #849"
}
]
}
```

---

I need to de-serealize this into an object with Rest Sharp so I can use the data in a client. My class definition is as below

```
public class store
{
public string name{get;set;}
}
public class Result
{
public store[] stores;
}
```

I use the line below to deserealize the rest response

```
var response = client.Execute<Result>(request);
```

Also tried result defination as below with the same result.

```
public class Result
{
public List<store> stores;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The member "stores" in Result class should be a property :

```
public class Result
{
    public List<store> stores { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic data type to deserealize.

```
var response = _client.Execute<dynamic>(request);
```